# Zend_Mail - read Gmail messages via POP

Tags: zend-framework, gmail, pop3, zend-mail

I am trying to read my Gmail account with Zend_Mail. The request just seems to time out. Is there an issue with my `$config`?

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $config = array(
        'host'=> 'pop.gmail.com',
        'user' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'ssl' => 'tls',
        'port' => 995);

    $mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3($config);
    $maxMessage = $mail->countMessages();
    $this->view->maxMessage = $maxMessage;

    $message = $mail->getMessage(1);
    $this->view->message = $message;
}
```

Comment: localhost for the moment while i'm dev testing ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use SSL as the ssl type.  Also, are you using your full email as the username?

```
$config = array('host'=> 'pop.gmail.com',
        'user' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'ssl' => 'SSL',
        'port' => 995);
```

Comment: Also, I found this code sample you might be able to use: http://code.google.com/p/zoop/source/browse/trunk/apps/request/bin/downloadEmails.php?r=446

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to enter ssl and port in case of gmail.
your config should be

```
$config = array('host'=> 'pop.gmail.com',
        'user' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx');
```